# Windows Insider Service is starting automatically every 30 mins crashing mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, service

I have a website on two servers (Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2012).  On the 2016 server mysql is crashing every 30 minutes.  In trying to track down what could be causing it I noticed that "**Windows Insider Service**" enters a running state right before mysql crashes every time.

The weird thing is that the **Windows Insider Service is set to a Manual Startup** Type so I don't understand why it's starting up every 30 minutes, yet this is what I see in my event log right before every mysql crash.

```
"The Windows Insider Service service entered the running state."  Event ID 7036
```

And when I say "right before" I mean at the exact same second, but listed just before the mysql crash in the event log.  I'm assuming that means it happened a fraction of a second before the mysql crash.

Thankfully I'm running ipSentry on my server which automatically detects the mysql crash and restarts it right away.  So mysql is automatically restarted and then approximately 55 seconds after mysql enters the running state, the Windows Insider Service enters the stopped state (or at least that's when it's recording in Windows event log).

**And exactly 30 minutes after mysql enters the running state, the Windows Insider Service also enters the running state, causing mysql to crash again.**

Also, mysql is not crashing on my 2012 Server, presumably because there is no Windows Insider Service on that version of the operating system, so I'm pretty sure this is what's causing mysql to crash.

To confirm my suspicions I want to obviously prevent this service from starting.  My question is, how can I find out what's causing it to start, and if I can't find that out, then is there a way to make sure it doesn't start?

UPDATE:  I noticed that the **Windows Error Reporting Service** is also starting up at the exact same second that the Windows Insider Service is starting (yet listed ahead of the Insider Service), and that service is triggered to restart automatically after 2 minutes when it fails.  I also noticed that exactly 1 minute after the Windows Insider Service enters the stopped state, so does the Windows Error Reporting Service.

So this seems to be the process:

1. Windows Error Reporting Service starts
2. Windows Insider Service starts
3. MySQL service stops (Steps 1 to 3 all at the same time)
4. ipSentry automatically restarts MySQL
5. Exactly 1 minute after Windows Insider Service started, it stops
6. Exactly 2 minutes after Windows Error Reporting started, it stops
7. Exactly 30 minutes after MySQL starts the entire cycle begins again

These are the settings for Windows Error Reporting Service.

[image]

So obviously I don't see anywhere in these settings that would cause the Windows Error Reporting service to stop after 2 minutes, and I also don't see any setting that would cause it to restart exactly 30 minutes after MySQL starts.  I also don't understand why these two services (Error Reporting & Insider Service) seem to be joined at the hip.

My main goal here is to stop MySQL from crashing.  I'm only bringing up these services because they seem to be the cause and I don't understand why they're doing what they're doing so I'm not sure how to stop it.

Comment: This link may be helpful 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/685091c9-95dc-42a8-8f71-3384720c3288/disable-windows-server-2016-startup-programs

Comment: Have you considered TAKE NO ACTION for all of Windows Error Reporting Services since this seems to trigger MySQL rolling over.  Are your running a licensed or preview version of 2016 that may have involvement with Windows Insider Service activities?

Comment: Hey Wilson.  You may not have noticed it was me asking the question, but thanks for your responses.  It's Windows Server 2016 Standard.  No preview version or anything like that so I obviously don't need the Windows Insider service.

Comment: I am aware of past efforts to assist.  Have you found this tip?  
start -> RUN -> msconfig ->startup tab-> select the programs and manage it accordingly.   What happens if you always TAKE NO ACTION in Windows Error Reporting Services, since that seems to trigger the Windows Insider Service activity?

Comment: I'm hesitant to do that because I'm thinking that's a useful service and I do want it to be running, however I'm trying it now.  At the very least it will confirm for me if that's the problem.

Comment: In 4 hours you will know.

Comment: Does setting a service to start on system startup maybe also force it to restart after crashing?

Comment: Yes, it will because it is essentially blind to crash history.

Comment: I did as you suggested Wilson but mysql still crashed.  However, Windows Insider Service is no longer appearing in the logs, only Windows Error Reporting Service.   So perhaps it's the Error Reporting Service that's the culprit, not the Insider Service.

Comment: What happens if you always TAKE NO ACTION in Windows Error Reporting Services?   And have it MANUAL in startup?

Comment: It's still automatically starting 30 minutes after MySQL crashes (with TAKE NO ACTION and MANUAL startup).  I have no idea what is triggering it, but since removing Windows Insider Service from startup in msconfig stopped that particular service from spontaneously starting, I'm betting the same will be true for Windows Error Reporting.  I've just removed it from msconfig so we'll know soon enough.

Comment: Coincidentally I found another thread on answers.microsoft.com that claims Windows Error Reporting was causing Control Panel to crash.  I think the thing is just plain buggy.

Comment: Turns out this is unrelated to mysql crashing.  I stopped Windows Error Reporting from running but mysql still crashes.

Comment: Do you have historical error logs?  After restart, is the last error log available?  If so, please post last 400 lines to allow analysis.  Thanks

Comment: I've looked through the mysqlerror logs at each crash and there's no pattern.  Sometimes it happens after losing connection, sometimes it happens after a connection timeout but there also is usually a gap of at least a minute between such an error or warning and mysql restarting, so it doesn't look like there's a link at all between those events.

Comment: Last 400 lines:  https://pastebin.com/raw/Ffc6b5qX

Comment: Solomon Globals:  https://pastebin.com/raw/tVAp2sur

Comment: Serenity Globals:  https://pastebin.com/raw/j3vhnBWi

Comment: Where is your ipsentry from (City, State of vendor)?  Website?  Thanks

Comment: The error log is from Serenity.

Comment: Serenity Global Status:  https://pastebin.com/raw/UvX9XSM9

Comment: Solomon Global Status:  https://pastebin.com/raw/mw0bvaBw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Windows Insider Service was not what was causing the MySQL crash every 30 minutes so this entire question was a wild goose chase, but for the benefit of others who may stumble across it I will post my solution here.

Turns out mysql installs on Windows still default the flush time to 1800 seconds (on nix boxes this value defaults to 0). Normally this is not a problem, but because I was using federated tables it was a problem. I guess mysql doesn't know how to flush federated tables, therefore crash. So I set `flushtime = 0` in my.ini and the problem went away.

This bug has been reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47525&thanks=3&notify=87